# Torsion in an $R$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $R = \mathbb Z[x,x^{-1},y,y^{-1}]$ be the ring of Laurent polynomials in variables $x$ and $y$. Let $M$ be an $R$-module generated by the infinite set $ \{a_0,b_0,a_1,b_1,...\}$.
>
> The following relations also hold in $M$:
> $$ xa_0 + yb_0 = xa_1 + yb_1,\  xa_1 + yb_1 = xa_2 + yb_2, ...$$
> What can I say about $M$?

Does the first relation imply $a_0 = a_1$? (I assume not...)
Is $M$ free? is $M$ torsion-free? is $M$ torsionless?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, the first question seems quite unlikely to happen. Why do you believe it so?